# Macro to skip Column A and strips out lower case letters

Tags: regex, excel, vba

- In column `A`, I have a list of sentences
- In columns `B-Z`, I have strings contain numbers followed by letters both uppercase and lower case.

such as

> 45ABc

The following macro strips all lowercase letters in the entire work sheet -  do not want it to strip any letters in column A. Please help.

```
Sub RegExReplace()

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegEx.Global = True

    RegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Z0-9_-]"
    For Each objCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        objCell.Value = RegEx.Replace(objCell.Value, "")
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your pattern should be exact in what you want to remove - not keep. See my post below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Sub RegExReplace()
    Dim objCell As Range
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegEx.Global = True

    RegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Z0-9_-]"
    For Each objCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If objCell.Column<>1 Then objCell.Value = RegEx.Replace(objCell.Value, "")
    Next

End Sub
```

or if you know that values that should be replaced only in columns `B:Z`, you can use next code as well:

```
Sub RegExReplace()
    Dim rng As Range, objCell As Range

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegEx.Global = True


    RegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Z0-9_-]"

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("B:Z"))
    End With

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each objCell In rng
            objCell.Value = RegEx.Replace(objCell.Value, "")
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for fixing the `B:Z` portion, but I think the OP's pattern also needs addressing.

Answer (score 1):

I've added code that:

1. Fixes your pattern to remove what you want to remove directly - ie `a-z` - rather than what you want to preserve (currently `A-Z-_` but could be much larger).
2. To use quicker arrays rather than range loops.

   ```
   Sub objRegexReplace()
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Dim objRegex As Object
   Dim X
   Dim lngRow As Long
   Dim lngCol As Long

   Set rng1 = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("B:Z"))
   X = rng1.Value2

   If rng1.Cells.Count > 1 Then
   Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
   With objRegex
       .Global = True
       .Pattern = "[a-z]+"
       .ignorecase = False
   For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
       For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
           X(lngRow, lngCol) = .Replace(X(lngRow, lngCol), vbNullString)
       Next
   Next
   rng1.Value2 = X
   End With
   Else
   MsgBox "No range to work on", vbCritical
   End If

   End Sub
   ```